# finding all paths in a graph including a vertex

Tags: r, graph, extract, vertex, subgraph

I have a directed simple graph (named tutti) and a list of vertex (named risultato).

I want to find the full set of subgraph extracted by "tutti" that includes a vertex in the array risultato.

As example in the included picture the graph tutti

[image]

Given the vertex 609 (that is one vertex present in risultato) (in red on the left) i need to plot the graph in picture

[image]
How can i extract all those graphs?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for providing a figure. It is still a little unclear what you need. Can you try and produce a small example of a graph and how you want to extract some nodes giving your expected output. Your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968678/get-node-descendants-in-a-tree-graph/27969283#comment44361509_27969283) gives details on how to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi, in the mean while i succeeded in solving in a very rude and not elegant way my problem. Starting from the vertex to study (in the array "risultato")  i used the following statement: sottografierrorisotto<-graph.neighborhood (tutti,vcount(tutti),risultato, "in")  and then the other sottografierrorisopra<-graph.neighborhood (tutti,vcount(tutti),risultato, "out") so i unified them with graph.union to have the upper and lower sides of the vertexes .... and that was all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertexes to be taken in consideration are in the array risultato.

## return all path in "tutti"  graph arriving to each element in risultato:

sottografierrorisopra<-graph.neighborhood (tutti,vcount(tutti),risultato, "in")

## return all path in "tutti" graph starting from the vertex in the risultato #array

sottografierrorisotto<-graph.neighborhood (tutti,vcount(tutti),risultato, "out")

## union of the graphs

zz<- graph.union (sottografierrorisopra, sottografierrorisotto)